# Typescript - "Authorization" does not exist on type HeadersInit

Tags: typescript, node-fetch

I'm using the `node-fetch` npm module and have a helper function for making authorized requests to a third party service (basically just middleware for adding in the Authorization header).

```js
async function makeAuthorizedRequest(url: string, options: RequestInit) {
  if (!options) {
    options = { headers: {} as HeadersInit }
  }
  if (!options.headers) {
    options.headers = {} as HeadersInit
  }
  options.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`
  if (!options.headers['User-Agent']) {
    options.headers['User-Agent'] = USERAGENT
  }
  return fetch(url, options)
}
```

The `RequestInit` type is defined as having a `headers` property of type `HeadersInit` defined as the following

```js
export type HeadersInit = Headers | string[][] | { [key: string]: string };
```

I get two distinct errors in my IDE (VSCode) and `tsc` refuses to compile this because

```
Property 'Authorization' does not exist on type 'Headers'.ts(2339)
```

and

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"User-Agent"' can't be used to index type 'HeadersInit'.
  Property 'User-Agent' does not exist on type 'HeadersInit'.ts(7053)
```

Now obviously "User-Agent" and "Authorization" are valid http headers, and from my understanding the type `{[key: string]: string}` definition should allow for this since "User-Agent" and "Authorization" are strings and their values are being set as strings. Why is tsc not able to see this and how can I actually fix it?

(I've used `//@ts-ignore` on the affected lines in the past, but I'd like to understand what its concerned about and how to fix this in the future - because having ts-ignore all over the codebase does not look professional)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:

```
const headersInit: HeadersInit = {};
options.header = headersInit;
```

Generally you want to avoid Type Assertion (`as`) if possible.

Alternative solution: if you know `options.headers` is neither a `Headers` or a `string[][]`  you can do this:

```
options.headers = {} as { [key: string]: string }
```

or the equivalent

```
options.headers = {} as Record<string, string>
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved these errors by realizing `HeadersInit` and `Headers` are two different types. So if someone is facing a similar issue, try something like this:

```js
const headers = options?.headers ? new Headers(options.headers) : new Headers();
    
if (!headers.has("Authorization")) {
    headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${authToken});
}
```

Not exactly the same as the question but I thought this worth sharing.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Learned that `HeadersInit` and `Headers` are two different things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `HeadersInit` type is not defined with ways to change the items. But it is defined to be compatible with `string[][]`, `Record<string, string>`, and `Headers`. Using a `Headers` object that you can easily manipulate as a substitute for a `HeadersInit` literal object, your code could work rewritten as:

```
  async function makeAuthorizedRequest(url: string, options: RequestInit) {
    // Redefining is unnecessary because the parameter must be a defined RequestInit.
    //if (!options) {
    //  options = {} as RequestInit;
    //}
    // A Headers object can be assigned to HeadersInit.
    // const means the variable is immutable, not its content.
    const reqHeaders = new Headers(options.headers);
    // Use `set` in case a header already exists in the collection.
    reqHeaders.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${access_token}`);
    if (!reqHeaders.get('User-Agent')) {
      reqHeaders.set('User-Agent', USERAGENT);
    }
    // Use the updated headers collection in the request.
    options.headers = makeHeaders;
    return fetch(url, options);
  }
```

I have assumed you had `access_token` and `USERAGENT` assigned already.